# WHERE NOT EXISTS SQL statement in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, not-exists

My code is this:

```
import sqlite3
def connect():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, author text, year integer)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
def insert(title, author, year):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)", (title, author, year))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
connect()
insert("Title", "Author", 1950)
```

I would like to use the WHERE NOT EXISTS SQL statement in order to avoid duplicate inputs. I tried different ways of writing in the WHERE NOT EXISTS along the cur.execute() but keep getting:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicate inserts, use a unique index or constraint:

```
create unique index unq_book_title_author_year on book(title, author, year);
```

This is better than `not exists` because the database enforces the uniqueness.  Do note that the `insert` will be attempted and then fail, if duplicate insertions are attempted.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff suggests, a unique index will cause attempts to duplicate index entries to raise an exception. The key here is to ask yourself _what needs doing_ in the situation you wish to detect. Presumably the user should be made aware that the attempted entry already exists.

Comment: I see, unfortunately I don't seem to know how to implement the unique index for my code  (keep getting a syntax error). Just out of curiosity, I would want as well to see the WHERE NOT EXISTS SQL statement at work in my code.

Comment: @DanielC.Tremură . . . https://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

Comment: Unfortunately the SQL `INSERT` statement is just that - insertion of a row into a table, with no conditions permissible. The syntax is described [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html). You might want to consider `INSERT OR REPLACE`, but this still won't pick duplicates up without the index.